# In bluemix liberty apps how to use the Environment variables in server.xml

Tags: environment-variables, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, server.xml

I have a Bluemix application pushed as a liberty buildpack. I would like to set some values in the server.xml, which are set using Environment variables for the app. Following is the snippet from my server.xml on how I tried to access the Environment variable. It is not working as expected. Please let me know if I miss something here.

```
<server>
<jndiEntry jndiName="myKey" value="${process.env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE}"/> 
</server>
```

Also, if there is any other approach please suggest. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it should just be

```
<server>
  <jndiEntry jndiName="myKey" value="${env.MY_ENV_VARIABLE}"/> 
</server>
```

If you're using Liberty on Bluemix, often it's not necessary to configure things like JNDI entries, because [auto configuration](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/autoConfig.html) will automatically add entries for many types of bound services (such as databases and SSO).

Another nice practice for configuring Bluemix apps (which may or may not be right for this use case) is to use [user-provided services](http://heidloff.net/article/16.12.2014110019NHEDRA.htm) for deployment-specific information. Your application would then parse the configuration information out of the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable.